# sphinx remove chapter title in my pdf with latexpdf?

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I generate a documentation from rst to pdf with latexpdf and sphinx.

How can I remove chapter title before every chapter?

```
-----------

CHAPTER ONE

-----------
```

Comment: I don't understand why the answers here are rated pretty high for not actually properly answering the question.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the [sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html) you can change the `latex_documents` documentclass to a howto documentclass, which will get rid of the "Chaper" before your section. However, this will also change formatting slightly for the whole build.

> documentclass: Normally, one of 'manual' or 'howto' (provided by Sphinx). Other document classes can be given, but they must include the “sphinx” package in order to define Sphinx’ custom LaTeX commands. “howto” documents will not get appendices. Also, howtos will have a simpler title page.

Just edit your `conf.py` and change `manual` to `howto`.

```
latex_documents = [
  ('index', 'foo.tex', u'foo Documentation',
   u'bar', 'howto'),
]
```

Comment: The simpler title page break all the defaut layout I get with 'manual' parameter. I thought there is a more convenient solution. thank you anyway

Answer (score 4):

As for the Chapter titles, from the [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#latex-options) and [LaTeX customization](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html):

> Inclusion of the “fncychap” package (which makes fancy chapter
> titles), default '\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}' for English
> documentation, '\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}' for internationalized
> docs (because the “Bjarne” style uses numbers spelled out in English).
> Other “fncychap” styles you can try include “Lenny”, “Glenn”, “Conny”
> and “Rejne”. You can also set this to '' to disable fncychap.

```
latex_elements = {
    'fncychap': '\\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}',
    # ...
}
```

Also, I was trying to search for how to remove the **Title page**, and a search brought me here, so I thought I'd add my answer here.

To remove the title page, just set the following options:

```
latex_elements = {
    'maketitle': '',  # No Title Page
    # ...
}
```