# How to force sphinx to use \section instead of \chapter

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I don't want to have any chapters in my sphinx documentation. Instead I want to use sections in my pdf output.

How can I tell sphinx to generate the intermediate `.tex` output starting at `\section` instead of `\chapter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sphinx remove chapter title in my pdf with latexpdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120632/sphinx-remove-chapter-title-in-my-pdf-with-latexpdf)

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120632/sphinx-remove-chapter-title-in-my-pdf-with-latexpdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following option in your `conf.py`:

```
latex_toplevel_sectioning = 'section'
```